# Lotus notes 6.5 inser carriage return in .csv file

Tags: lotus-notes

by using lotus notes script, how can i insert into a .csv file a carriage return ? because if i try to do this using chr(10) or chr(13) function in the .csv file i see a "small box" like  instead the carrige return.

Example - my script is this:

```
record=record & {"} & doc.ColumnValues (n)  & {"} & Chr(10)
Call stream.WriteText(record)
```

and on my .csv file the output is:

```
field1,field2,field3,...,field99,□,field1,field2,field3,...,field99
```

but on my .csv file i want this:

```
field1,field2,field3,...,field99
field1,field2,field3,...,field99
```

how can i obtain this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you didn't read the documentation (Lotus Domino Designer 6.5 Help) for the NotesStream- Class:

> Syntax
>
> bytes& = notesStream.WriteText( text$ , **[ eol& ]** )
>
> Parameters
>
> text$
>
> String. The text to write, to a maximum of 2GB bytes.
>
> eol&
>
> Constant of type Long. End-of-line character(s) appended to the text.
>   The default is EOL_NONE.
>    - EOL_CR (2) appends a carriage return (ASCII 13).
>    **- EOL_CRLF (0) appends a carriage return and line feed (ASCII 10 + 13).**
>    - EOL_LF (1) appends a line feed (ASCII 10).
>    - EOL_NONE (5) appends nothing. Default.
>    - EOL_PLATFORM (3) follows the conventions of the current platform.

That your code simply should look like that:

```vb
record=record & {"} & doc.ColumnValues (n)  & {"}
Call stream.WriteText(record, EOL_CRLF)
```

If you didn't `%include "lsconst.lss"`, then the second line might be:

```vb
Call stream.WriteText(record, 0)
```

I took your example although in the record- line it is missing the comma as separator, it should rather look like that to be correct, but I guess that was only a "reduce the code to an absolute minimum"- error in your post rather than in your "real" code.

```vb
If record = "" then
  record = {"} & doc.ColumnValues (n)  & {"}
Else
  record = record & {,"} & doc.ColumnValues (n)  & {"}
End If
```